# Why there is no authentication popup on IISExpress but on IIS

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis, windows-authentication, iis-express, intranet

I'm new on ASPNet MVC 5, I'm confused about IISExpress. I am developing intranet site and I use windows authentication. After publish and run site on IIS I saw that authentication pop-up which not came on IISExpress. Why there is something like this? After searched about preventing that pop-up I saw that I have to add site to trusted website, however, I didn't do this for IISExpress, did IISExpress do it for me automatically? In addition to this I have a problem about [EWS Managed API on IIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39634426/ews-account-that-does-not-have-a-mailbox-error-on-iis)

Answer (score 1):

IIS Express is a process that runs in the context of the currently logged on user, meaning you. Your account usually has enough (or too much) permissions to access files and other resources.

The 'big' IIS uses different user accounts to run your application, these accounts have limited permissions and may not have access to files and resources. If IIS can't access a file with its normal process account, it needs a different account to access that file and asks for one in a popup.